# Run program and intercept and redirect syscalls

Tags: linux, strace, syscalls

I would like to run a program, and when that program attempts to read a specific file, I would like it to read a different file of my choosing instead.

Specifically, the program attempts to read a configuration file, and is poorly designed and doesn't allow the user to specify the location of the configuration file. I also don't have permission to edit the file at the location the program attempts to read from.

I know it's possible to *detect* syscalls made by the program using `strace`, and I am able to see the sole `open()` syscall made by the program by running it under `strace`. It there any way to *intercept* that syscall and change it's behaviour to open a different file of my choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LD_PRELOAD` can do this on linux; first up our application to modify, `app.c`

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char c;
    int fd;
    fd = open(*++argv, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, &c, 1);
    printf("%c\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

which serves to read a character from a file:

```
$ make app
cc     app.c   -o app
$ echo a > a
$ echo b > b
$ ./app a ; ./app b
a
b
```

changing this up requires a library that fakes out `open`, `fakeopen.c`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int (*orig_open) (const char *path, int oflag, ...);

int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...)
{
    orig_open fn;
    mode_t cmode = 0;
    va_list ap;
    if ((oflag & O_CREAT) == O_CREAT) {
        va_start(ap, oflag);
        cmode = (mode_t) va_arg(ap, int);
        va_end(ap);
    }
    if (strncmp(path, "a", 2) == 0)
        path = getenv("FAKE");
    fn = (orig_open) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
    return fn(path, oflag, cmode);
}
```

which when compiled and used via `LD_PRELOAD` and when the filename is what we're looking for and assuming `FAKE` has something that is the path:

```
$ cat Makefile
fakeopen.so: fakeopen.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -fPIC -ldl fakeopen.c -o fakeopen.so
$ rm fakeopen.so
$ cat Makefile
fakeopen.so: fakeopen.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -fPIC -ldl fakeopen.c -o fakeopen.so
$ make fakeopen.so
cc  -shared -fPIC -ldl fakeopen.c -o fakeopen.so
$ FAKE=b LD_PRELOAD=`pwd`/fakeopen.so ./app a
b
```

we can make `./app a` instead read file `b`. Of course there will need to be more error checking and other rakes that may be stepped on, but this should be the gist of modifying an `open(2)` call.

Comment: that will only work if open(2) is called directly, not via fopen(3); eg. your `fakeopen.so` will work will `cat file` but not with `sort file`. And it's the same with all libc functions that call open(2) internally.

Comment: This is not syscall redirection, it's redirection of calls to functions defined in shared objects.