# How can I redirect the output of a C program from /dev/tty to /dev/null?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, tty, c, controlling-terminal

Consider this sample C program which writes to `/dev/tty` and doesn't have command line options to make it not do so.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    FILE* fout = fopen("/dev/tty", "w");
    fprintf(fout, "Hello, World!\n");
    fclose(fout);
}
```

How could I redirect the output of it to `/dev/null` in a shell script?

P.S. I read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597137/how-to-redirect-output-from-dev-tty-to-dev-null), but I didn't understand much. In any case, I'm expecting an answer that doesn't modify the code source of the program.

Comment: why do you open /dev/tty when you mean to open /dev/null?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's just a sample program. The original program open `/dev/tty` and I would want to redirect it to `/dev/null` when running tests on it. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

TL,DR:

```
script -c myprogram /dev/null </dev/null >/dev/null
```

---

You can't “redirect” `/dev/tty` in the same sense that you can redirect standard output. Standard output is defined as a file descriptor. Programs write to whatever file is already open on file descriptor 1 when they start. Some operating systems offer `/dev/stdout` as a file that's equivalent to standard output, but it's an “alias” for standard output. In contrast, `/dev/tty` is a file name, which refers to the process's controlling terminal. If a program opens `/dev/tty`, explicitly it opens `/dev/tty`, and that can't be redirected.

What you can do is run the program with a controlling terminal that isn't the same as the controlling terminal of the program that runs it. A simple way to do this is with the [`script` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unix)). In its simplest form:

```
script -c myprogram /dev/null >/dev/null
```

When `myprogram` runs and opens `/dev/tty`, this is a terminal provided by `script`, not the terminal in which `script` runs. What `script` does when it detects a write on the terminal is to both write to its own standard output and write to the indicated typescript file; hence I set both `script`'s standard output and the typescript file to `/dev/null`.

If `myprogram` reads from the terminal, `script` reads from its own standard input, so you'll probably want to redirect this to `/dev/null` as well.

Note that `script` does not pass the exit status of `myprogram` to its caller. Some implementations (e.g. the one in Debian and derivatives) have a `-e` option to do that.

Comment: Many thanks! The answer covers everything I need (exit status etc.). I didn't know the existence of `script`.

Comment: Interesting. Essentially, /dev/tty is also an abstraction layer, which can be exploited.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Right, it's "magic", not a real fixed device like your /dev/ttyS0 serial port or /dev/tty1 text console terminal: opening it depends on the state of something else (your controlling TTY).  So in that respect it's like `/dev/stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

It's **very** unusual that a program would open /dev/tty itself. If you need to print something to the console, you'd just write to standard output, `stdout`, which you could redirect, as [Gilles shows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647843/how-to-redirect-output-of-a-c-program-from-dev-tty-to-dev-null/647847#647847).

Your only choice here would be intercepting the [libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) `fopen` call, unless that's been inlined (which isn't that rare) or the underlying operating system `open` call and bend it.

It's not that hard. You'd need to write a small library that contains said `open` function, which in turn calls the actual `open` function after having "sanitized" its input (i.e., if the file name is /dev/tty, replace it with /dev/null).

*[Run program and intercept and redirect syscalls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484368/run-program-and-intercept-and-redirect-syscalls)* shows how that's done.

Comment: As Gilles shows, you *can* “redirect” `/dev/tty`, by changing the program’s controlling terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I understand what you mean though it's not what I'm looking for. The program I'm dealing with is Git. See [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/compat/terminal.c#L212).

Comment: Um, that feels like an XY problem: are you sure you want to test an interactive `git` when you're redirecting tty to /dev/null? Wouldn't that sound like you want to use git non-interactively, which you can achieve through easier means?

Comment: It is not unusual at all to open /dev/tty for interactive programs.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica absolutely, but that's usually the job of things like readline or ncurses, and then the solution to working without their output is configuring them accordingly, or preloading different implementations of their functionality alltogether.