How can I get stderr from mbuffer written to log file when using tee?
Having a bash script that essential only doing:
mbuffer --md5 -i dummy.tar -o /dev/null

A user of this script wants to use tee and store the output messages in a log file.
./script.sh 2>&1 | tee log.txt

Everything is visible on terminal but nothing is written to log.txt.
How can I do to get output on both terminal and in file?
Just running in a terminal winds up the same, nothing in log.txt:
mbuffer --md5 -i dummy.tar -o /dev/null 2>&1 | tee log.txt

Tried on Ubuntu and Rocky Linux.
Also tried
stdbuf -e 0 -o 0 mbuffer --md5 -i dummy.tar -o /dev/null 2>&1 | tee log.txt


Answer
From the mbuffer manpage:

-l <file>
      Log messages to file instead of standard error output.


and

-q    Quiet - do not display the status on the standard error output.


Combining those two options, we get:
#!/bin/sh
# Contents of script.sh
# Usage: ./script.sh inputfile outputfile

mbuffer --md5 -q -l /dev/stderr -i "$1" -o "$2"

so we can execute:
$ ./script.sh dummy.tar /dev/null 2>&1 | tee log.txt
libmd5:md5 hash: f7e6e6d8924614a8d6655f00471e6b77
libmd5:md5 hash: f7e6e6d8924614a8d6655f00471e6b77
summary:  148 kiByte in  0.0sec - average of 44.5 MiB/s
$ cat log.txt
libmd5:md5 hash: f7e6e6d8924614a8d6655f00471e6b77
libmd5:md5 hash: f7e6e6d8924614a8d6655f00471e6b77
summary:  148 kiByte in  0.0sec - average of 44.5 MiB/s

Note: The duplicate lines with hashes in the output (and the log) can be removed by piping the output to uniq(1) prior to sending it to tee(1):
$ ./script.sh dummy.tar /dev/null 2>&1 | uniq | tee log.txt
libmd5:md5 hash: f7e6e6d8924614a8d6655f00471e6b77
summary:  148 kiByte in  0.0sec - average of 44.5 MiB/s
$ cat log.txt
libmd5:md5 hash: f7e6e6d8924614a8d6655f00471e6b77
summary:  148 kiByte in  0.0sec - average of 44.5 MiB/s

Explanation
This misbehavior is caused by the fact that the program mbuffer is controlling its output in an unusual way (it is being "too smart"): if there is a controlling terminal present, file descriptor associated with stderr is passed as the second argument to dup2(2) in mbuffer.c lines 1287-1296:
int tty = open("/dev/tty",O_RDWR);
if (-1 == tty) {
        Terminal = 0;
        if ((Autoloader == 0) && (OutFile))
                warningmsg("No controlling terminal and no autoloader command specified.\n");
} else {
        Terminal = 1;
        err = dup2(tty,STDERR_FILENO);
        assert(err != -1);
}

This essentially explicitly redirects stderr to /dev/tty.
Off topic: this is also a misuse of assert(3). Run-time errors shouldn't be passed to it, but preconditions, invariants and postconditions.

If I understand it correctly, a user of the script can not capture in a file what is seen on the terminal then? Only the messages from mbuffer, not a combined log of previous output and md5 from mbuffer. The script is basically doing tar -cvf - dir | mbuffer --md5  -o /dev/null

That is correct. The program mbuffer overrides the redirects. Fortunately, it has options to control output, which is what this answer is based on. The only way you could capture what is sent to "stderr" (which the program force-redirects to /dev/tty) would be to somehow redirect /dev/tty (hypothetically, that could be done by the kernel if there was such an option).

Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647847/367454 ("... You can't “redirect” /dev/tty in the same sense that you can redirect standard output.").

The link above was really useful! Using script -c solved my core problem, to get a combined output to file.

@TopCatSE I updated the answer to better match your question. I changed the script.sh to accept input and output files as arguments.

Perfect, the updated script works! What puzzled me was that this does not work tar -cvf - dir | mbuffer --md5  -l /dev/stderr -o /dev/null -q  2>&1 | tee log.txt.

As stated, mbuffer is taking a very nonstandard approach to output. Some messages are written to a "log", some to "stderr", "stderr" is by default (without -l) hardcoded to dup2(2) /dev/tty... everything is in the source, which is in many places hard to follow.

Try this: ( exec 2>&1; tar -cvf - dir | mbuffer --md5 -l /dev/stderr -o /dev/null -q; ) | tee log.txt. This redirects stderr in the entire subshell created by ().
